# evaluate a string as a property in C#

Tags: c#, properties

I have a property stored in a string... say Object `Foo` has a property `Bar`, so to get the value of the `Bar` property I would call..

```
Console.Write(foo.Bar);
```

Now say that I have `"Bar"` stored in a string variable...

```
string property = "Bar"

Foo foo = new Foo();
```

how would I get the value of `foo.Bar` using `property`?

***How I'm use to doing it in PHP***

```
$property = "Bar";

$foo = new Foo();

echo $foo->{$property};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
var barValue = foo.GetType().GetProperty("Bar").GetValue(foo, null)
```

Answer (score 3):

You would use reflection:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = foo.GetType().GetProperty(property);
object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(foo, null);
```

The `null` in the call there is for indexed properties, which is not what you have.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use reflection to do this.

Something like this should take care of you

```
foo.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(foo, null);
```