# Extending Enums with Custom Attributes and const values issue

Tags: c#, enums, custom-attributes

I implemented `Custom Attributes` for `enum` using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/143742/Extending-Enums-with-Custom-Attributes) article, everything is fine with `hard coding` values, but I need to pass the parameters in `run time`, for example:

```
enum MyItems{
    [CustomEnumAttribute("Products", "en-US", Config.Products)]
    Products
}
```

The `Config.Products (bool value)` is the problem, the error is:

`An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type`

Is there any way to fix this?

**Update**

The `enum` (MyItems in this case) have 20 items, each item must have that `custom attribute`, then I want to generate menu from the Enum's items, depended on `Culture` I getting the matched title, also depended on `Config`, I decided to show/hide the item from the menu (in fact if Config.X == false, I don't add the item to the menu)

Also, for Config, I have another system and I wanna sync that system with the menu, that is the reason that I wanna get the `Config.X` in run-time.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of an attribute, you could create an extension method that find `Config.<enumName>`

Comment: Sorry, but didn't get you? I know how to create extension method, but how  I can mix this 2 things?

Comment: Can you get access to `Config.Products` inside the attribute constructor or static method `Get`?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension method

```
public string GetConfigValue(this MyItems myItem)
{
    return Config.GetType().GetProperty(myItem.ToString()).GetValue(Config, null);
}
```

This uses reflection to access the relevant property on the Config object. In the example you give, if myItem = Products then you can call

```
myItem.GetConfigValue()
```

And it should return the value of Config.Products

Related SO Questions:

- [Dynamic Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363722/evaluate-a-string-as-a-property-in-c-sharp)
- [Enum Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309333/enum-string-name-from-value)

---

Based on your update, I'd suggest this even more. Attributes must be constant values at compile time (hence the error you're getting). Even if you do not go the extension method route, you absolutely need some sort of method.

Comment: Config is a `Static Class`, and I got error with your code

Comment: @MehdiDehghani, try `.GetValue(null,null)` and also `typeof(Config)` instead `Config.GetType()`

Comment: @MehdiDehghani -> `typeof(Config)` instead `Config.GetType()`

Comment: Did you get my goal of the code? I think you got me incorrect.could you please tell me, how your code can help me to get `"Products", "en-US", false)`?Imaging I want to generate a menu from enum items

Comment: @MehdiDehghani, you should explain what you really try do

Answer (score 0):

No way to fix this, it's a limitation of attributes.

You can use static readonly fields in case you need a fixed set of objects with behaviour:

```
public class MyItems
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public string Locale { get; private set; }

    readonly Func<OtherThing> factory;

    public static readonly MyItems Products = new MyItems("Products", "en-US", () => Config.Products);
    public static readonly MyItems Food = new MyItems("Food", "en-GB", () => Config.FishAndChips);

    private MyItems(string name, string locale, Func<OtherThing> factory)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Locale = locale;
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public OtherThing GetOtherThing() {
        return factory();
    }
}
```

See another answer for a more complete example:
[C# vs Java Enum (for those new to C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469287/c-sharp-vs-java-enum-for-those-new-to-c)